# Unable to load media files in nginx

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, nginx, digital-ocean

I just deployed a django application on digitalocean and I'm having problems with nginx as it's not serving media files uploaded by users.

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
upstream app_server {
        server unix:/home/sayc/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.shelteratyourcrossroads.com;

        keepalive_timeout 5;
        client_max_body_size 4G;

        access_log /home/sayc/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/sayc/logs/nginx-error.log;

        location /static/ {
                alias /home/sayc/staticfiles/;
        }

        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
        location / {
                try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
}
```

Here are some settings in settings.py:

```
...
# Static
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Media
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

# CKEditor Configuration
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default' : {
        'toolbar' : None,
    }
}
...
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

The image fields in each of the classes in models.py file above means there are two subfolders in my media directory - `media/posts` and `media/users`. Also, there's another subfolder, `media/uploads` - this was added by the CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH setting. This makes three.

I hope this is enough to help debug what's wrong with my nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
location /media/ {
    alias /home/sayc/<project_name>/media/;  # change project_name
}
```

in your Nginx config.

Since

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')
```

I cannot guess full path to your media files:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: nginx: [emerg] location "/" is outside location "/media/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sayc:23